# AHK macro automation software: GUI does not show

Tags: windows, macros, autohotkey

I remember in the past I have used AHK to do some repetitive task.
I did it via some GUI; it recorded my mouse gestures and my keyboard strokes.
I have downloaded it again but now I see no GUI, just script language.
Can anyone suggest what the problem is or maybe some other free program?

Comment: Check the folder where AHK is located. There should be a few other binary files for different tools, including the GUI tool you mentioned above. I'm on my phone, so I can't verify my statement.

Comment: perhaps this is what you want: <installdir>\AutoScriptWriter\AutoScriptWriter.exe

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, it's located in `<install directory>\AutoHotkey\AutoScriptWriter`, most probably `C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoScriptWriter\AutoScriptWriter.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have downloaded something else . This [copy of AutoScriptWriter](http://rghost.net/50541378) works for me.
Also as you ask about other similar tool, I would advise you to try [Pulover's Macro Creator](http://www.macrocreator.com/).